# Jquery prevObject returned instead of the actual object (canvas). Why?

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this (a **div** whose id is "whole_page" and **one of the descendants is a canvas**)

```
<div id="whole_page">
    <div>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

If using **jQuery** I do:

```
console.log ($('#whole_page').find("canvas").length)
```

The output is **1** (indeed if finds the canvas, which I later extract as HTML DOM by .get(0) ).

But if I do (I'm writing a sort of jQuery plugin):

```
$.canvasjQ = $('#whole_page').find("canvas").length;
console.log($.canvasjQ);
```

The output is **0** (and obviusly I can't do .get(0) because $.canvasJQ is **undefined** ).

I used a lot $. as replacement of Javascript's "global variables" (**is this a bad practice?**), both for simple values or objects, and I got no problem like this.

Furthermore I would like to know if $. **is considered a global variable** ?

**EDIT**: if try to print (I also tried to invert the 2nd and 3rd lines of code)

```
$.canvasjQ = $('#whole_page').find("canvas")
console.log($.canvasjQ); // Output: [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], ...... 
console.log($('#whole_page').find("canvas")); // Output: [canvas, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: ....
```

Why is the **output differect (prevObject vs Canvas)** ? Indeed i expect the canvas, in fact if I write

```
console.log($('#whole_page').find("canvas").length;
```

result is **1**.
but if I write (which is supposed to be ** equivalent**)

```
console.log($.canvasjQ.length);
```

result is **0**

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/szQ4U/

Comment: How and when are you calling your `$.canvasjQ` code?  Are you sure the DOM is ready at that point?

Comment: *"The output is 0 (and obviusly I can't do .get(0) because $.canvasJQ is undefined )."* How can it be `undefined` if the output is `0`? O_o *"Furthermore I would like to know if $. is considered a global variable ?"* If `window.$ === $` is `true`, then yes, it is a global variable.

Comment: @ Rocket: yes, DOM is ready.I call the code within $(document).ready         @Felix: please see my updated question

Comment: Can you show us *exactly* how you using this code?  It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/szQ4U/1/  Can you use http://jsfiddle.net and make an example of your code to illustrate the issue?

Comment: We cannot really help you if we are not able to reproduce the problem.  To the best of our knowledge, you are setting `$.canvasjQ` before the DOM is ready or you are overwriting it with an empty jQuery object.

Comment: you are right. now I'm going to make some other test and if I can't figure out why I'll provide jsfiddle code :)

Comment: well, I tried to execute the code with setTimeout and somehow (even with 1ms delay!) works. But I'm very confused because $(document).ready should wait for full DOM load, but it doesn't seem to be true, neither in this case, nor in many more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the doublequotes in the canvas tag

http://jsfiddle.net/cKzBZ/

```
<div id="whole_page">
    <div>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw your code, but somehow for me doesn't work (the doublequotes were just a writing error here). please see my updated question

Comment: That's the only way it returns 0 for me... Everything works...

does it still return 0 with `$.canvasjQ = $("canvas",'#whole_page').length;` ?